# Did Voldemort know that his wand's core came from Fawkes?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

> "Exactly," said Dumbledore. "Harry's wand and Voldemorts wand share cores.
> Each of them contains a feather from the tail of the same phoenix. ***This* phoenix, in
> fact," he added, and he pointed at the scarlet-and-gold bird, perching peacefully on
> Harry's knee**. (*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Ch 36 - The Parting of the Ways)

Did Voldemort know that his wand's core originated with Fawkes?

If so, when did he find out?

<sub>NOTE: I'm asking only about **Fawkes**. We know that Voldemort found out about the twin cores after he kidnapped Ollivander and tortured that fact out of him.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

There is no canon evidence to say either way, but Ollivander knew where the twin core came from and told Voldemort about that, so there is no reason to believe that he wouldn't tell Voldemort about which Pheonix it came from.

Answer (score -3):

Yes he did thats why he asked too change wands after the first time their wands connected instead of trying again

Comment: This doesn't mean he knew it came from Fawkes. He knew there was a connection between his and Harry's wands, but may not have known that their wand core came from Dumbledore's phoenix.